# How to understand the structure of git command?

Tags: linux, git, command, command-line-interface

How to understand the structure of git command?

```
   git remote add origin repo-url
```

In the code above which one is a command and which one is a parameter?

Comment: Read the git man page?

Comment: Seriously though, despite my original tone, I do recommend the man pages. `man git-remote`, `man git-commit`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different command-line interpreters available on different systems, so for some of the details, the OS and/or your chosen shell matter.  You mention Linux (via the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) tag), so we might assume you are using bash, dash, fish, zsh, or perhaps even tcsh or some such.  These shells all vary slightly but they have a lot of things in common:

- They treat the first white-space-separated word as the command.  All remaining words are arguments.
- They do what the shells call [*glob expansion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), so that instead of programs having to interpret `*.py` for instance, the program just gets all the `.py` files as individual arguments.
- They perform *variable expansion*, such as replacing `$HOME` with your home directory.

(This is not the right place to discuss all of these details—find documentation for your particular shell, and read that, and/or read some Unix or Linux programming environment books.  StackOverflow and other StackExchange sites do have plenty of specific answers about specific shell programming constructs, though.)

In any case, given the command:

```
git remote add origin repo-url
```

the *shell's* responsibility is to break up the five words into an argument vector: `git`, `remote`, `add`, `origin`, and `repo-url`.  The zeroth argument<sup>1</sup> is the command to run, so the shell then locates this command (using `$PATH`) and runs it, passing all the arguments—including the command name itself—to the command.

Thus, at this point, the *command* is `git` and everything else is an argument to that command.  However, the `git` command itself acts like a miniature, non-interactive shell: it interprets its arguments, such as `remote`, to figure out which of these is a command.  So to Git, `remote` is a command, with arguments `add`, `origin`, and `repo-url`.  Git prefixes the command with `git-`, then locates the `git-remote` command—which resides in the directory that `git --exec-path` will print—and runs *that*, with arguments `add`, `origin`, and `url` (and zeroth argument `git-remote`).

So, having passed through the `git` command into the `git-remote` command, the arguments are now just `add`, `origin`, and `url` (with the command name `git-remote` available to `git-remote` as the zero'th argument).

Note that the `git` command itself takes (and handles and therefore takes away) some command options.  For instance, running:

```
git --work-tree=/tmp hello world
```

causes Git to save away the work-tree setting `/tmp`, then attempt to run the command `git-hello` with the argument `world`.  You can write your own Git commands by writing, e.g., a `git-hello` program: `git hello` will then run your `git-hello` program.  In any case, the `--work-tree` argument has vanished from the argument list at this point.  (Git has stored it in an environment variable, `$GIT_WORK_TREE`.  Environment variables are passed across `exec` system calls; `exec` is how the shell runs `git` and how Git runs its sub-commands.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This zeroth argument is often referred to as `argv[0]`, after the naming convention used in C language programming.

Answer (score 1):

[git cli book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-The-Command-Line) has detailed information on the git command line interface.

in your code, git remote is command and following it are the arguments.

> git-remote - Manage set of tracked repositories

Manage the set of repositories ("remotes") whose branches you track.

you can find subcommands for any git command by

```
git help <git_command>
```